# How do I divide using DAX in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following columns

```
Code | Amount
TY123 | 30
TY456 |60
TY789 |80
```

and so on

I want to find a percentage
I have to divide the distinct count of column Code by **Total Spends** ( Which is coming from a different table ) for each **country** ( Coming from a different table ) * 100

The resulting table should look like

```
Country | Code %
A |43%
B | 56%
```

And so on

How Do I go about this? I am highly confused.
I tried  the following measure but it is giving me wrong result[error : The function SUM cannot work with TYPE string]

`#measure = DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[Code]),SUM('Table2'[Total Spends]))*100`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: the formula itself looks good to me, the error "The function SUM cannot work with TYPE string" is self-explanatory, one of the columns you use is a string and not a number. Open Power Query and change its data type when you import it

Comment: Hi, on doing that it is replaced by ERROR and saying Cannot be changed.

Comment: (code) column here is of datatype string and that obviuosly cannot be changed....try this calculate(distinctcount(code)/sum(total spends))*100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code column looks like `TY123`, that's clearly a string data type column that doesn't make any sense to try to sum or divide.

Since you specify that you want to divide a **distinct count** of `Code` by `Total Spends`, use DISTINCTCOUNT instead of SUM.

```
measure =
DIVIDE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Code] ), SUM ( 'Table2'[Total Spends] ) ) * 100
```

DISTINCTCOUNT works on any column datatype and is the aggregator you are actually interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, I have upvoted and ticked your answer :)